# Translation-invariant product measure on $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\mu$ denote a fixed translation invariant product measure on $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ in which each state has positive probability.

I do not understand what is meant by

"in which each state has positive probability."

Do you know what may be meant?

Answer (score 1):

A translation invariant product probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ is $\mu=\bigotimes\limits_{\mathbb Z^d}\nu$ for some probability measure $\nu$ on $\{0,1,2\}$. The hypothesis is that $\nu(0)$, $\nu(1)$ and $\nu(2)$ are all positive.

Comment: Isn't this a Bernoulli-measure?

Comment: Other name, same object, except the positivity condition.

Comment: To make sure, we mean the same: What you write down is a measure that gives a cylinderset $[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$, where $x_i\in\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ the measure $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\nu(x_i)$?

Comment: Hmmm, what else? $ $

Comment: OK. Thank you. Only wanted to make sure.